# Convert geolocation into street address description

Tags: geolocation, mapping

Is there an existing service that would could turn a street address into a "friendly name" like "Corner of 46th & 7th" or "14th street between 1st & 2nd"?

I remember looking at one a few years ago but for the life of me cannot find it now.

If not, how might you go about doing this with popular geolocation services (like Google's)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Google Places. You'll need an API key (which is free) - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/

Comment: Google Places tells me the establishments near a given location, not the colloquial way to referrer to said location

Comment: Ah, I see. How about regular search - try searching for latitude and longtitude on Maps to see example. Sorry if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Google products are not free.